# When SQL server run same query second time than does SQL server generate execution plan again or use execution plan that is stored in cache memory?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am exploring performance tuning in SQL server and found that in SQL server best execution plan and statistics of query is stored in cache memory so just want to know that,

when SQL server run same query second time than does SQL server generate execution plan again or use  execution plan that is stored in cache memory ?

If both possible than based on which criteria SQL server will decide what to do recompile or use stored execution plan ?

Comment: It uses the cache (assuming nothing occurred that invalidates things, like an index being added or removed or statistics being updated). If it didn't, what would the purpose of the cache even be?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-query-plan-cache/):

> The duration that a query plan stays in the plan cache depends upon how often a query is executed. Query plans that are used more often, stay in the query plan cache for longer durations, and vice-versa.